# HibernateException

Tags: java, hibernate

when i execute this method

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void importFluxEquipement() throws HibernateException, SQLException
    {
        Session s = HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession();
        CallableStatement cs = s.connection().prepareCall("{call PK_COMPAS_FLUX_ISU.IMPORT_EQUIPEMENT_EAI()}");
        cs.execute();
        log.info("- Intégration du flux ISU Equipement");
    }
```

i have this error

> ERROR - org.hibernate.HibernateException: connection is not valid
>   without active transaction

Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `Transaction.beginTransaction()` method.

```
Session s = HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession();
Transaction trans=s.beginTransaction();
CallableStatement cs = s.connection().prepareCall("{call PK_COMPAS_FLUX_ISU.IMPORT_EQUIPEMENT_EAI()}");
cs.execute();
trans.commit();
```